# How to get the string with more ocurrences in a list

Tags: java

I have a List of Strings and I'm trying to have a method that tells me which String has more occurrences in the List.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
package codekata;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class OcurrenciasEnLista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        lista.add("test");
        lista.add("foo");
        lista.add("foo");
        lista.add("foo");
        lista.add("bar");
        lista.add("crack");
        moreOftenWord(lista);
    }

    private static void moreOftenWord(List<String> lista) {
        Map<String, Integer> mapa = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String palabra: lista)
            addOrIncrementCount(mapa, palabra);


    }

    private static void addOrIncrementCount(Map<String, Integer> counters,
            String toAdd) {

        Integer currValue = counters.get(toAdd);
        if (currValue == null)
            counters.put(toAdd, 1);
        else
        {
            counters.put(toAdd, currValue + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't know how to do is to return -the word- already in the `moreOftenWord` method.

Can anybody give me a clue on this?

Answer (score 5):

The most common element in a list is called the ["mode"](http://www.mathgoodies.com/lessons/vol8/mode.html) of the list.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/39745-get-mode-of-a-list/ is the first result for "mode of a list java" that looks relevant in case you want a code sample.

To get at the most common element after you've built your map of counters, you probably want to do something like

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> mode = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : counters.entrySet()) {
  if (mode == null || mode.value() < e.value()) {
    mode = e;
  }
}
// Most common string in mode.getKey()
```

This assumes that you redefine

```
Map counters
```

generically as

```
Map<String, Integer> counters
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#elementSet%28%29) data structure maintains a count of each element added to it. So you can remove all boilerplate code if you use this. Then all you need to do is iterate through the Multiset and find the element that has the max count.

Guava library has many such useful data structures and more.

Answer (score 0):

[In statistics, this is called the "mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)) (as [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8651549/521799) already explained). [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) is a library that supports [`mode()`](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/lambda/Collectable.html#mode--) on streams. The following program:

```
System.out.println(
    Seq.of("test", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "crack")
       .mode()
);
```

Yields:

```
Optional[foo]
```

(disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOλ)